# wicked_pdf part of the Chinese is not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6.1

wicked_pdf part of the Chinese is not displayed

It's strange, some Chinese characters are missing in the scheduled task for generating PDF, but they appear normally in the rails console. Testing on another server, the console is also not working properly. I have also used PDFkit, and the result is the same.

The service is centos